# Styling a button with repeat, but including two sides

Tags: html, css, button

**Hello,**

I'm just having a question, which may sound very dumb or noobish, but it's something I really like to know for future developments. I'm styling a button for the `<button>` tag in HTML. This is my code;

**CSS**

```
 button {
    line-height: 40px;
    height:50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background:transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.minebutton {
    font-family: "Minecraft Regular";
    font-size:15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-image: url("http://minecreate.net/includes/imaging/buttons/mcb_left.png"),
    url("http://minecreate.net/includes/imaging/buttons/mcb_middle.png"),
    url("http://minecreate.net/includes/imaging/buttons/mcb_right.png") !important;
    background-position: 0px 0px, left, right;
    background-size: 30px 100%, 30px 100%, 30px 100%;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat,repeat-x,no-repeat;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="minebutton" style="width:450px;">Don't click here</button>
```

The Question is, when I'm having this button, only the left side and the right middle appear, the right side doesn't appear on the far right side, and I think it's because of the 'repeat-x' in the middle image. How can I have the left part visible, and the middle part still repeating?

**Thank you,**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the image are [layered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds) in the given order so the second image hides the last one.  If you reorder the images and fix the `background-position` and `background-repeat` accordingly you'll probably get the result you want.

For instance :

```
background-image: url("http://minecreate.net/includes/imaging/buttons/mcb_left.png"),
url("http://minecreate.net/includes/imaging/buttons/mcb_right.png"),
url("http://minecreate.net/includes/imaging/buttons/mcb_middle.png") !important;
background-position: 0px 0px, right;
background-size: 30px 100%, 30px 100%, 30px 100%;
background-repeat:  no-repeat,no-repeat,repeat-x;
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u0w5dhtb/).

Comment: Thank you. This easy solution did it. I Didn't think about that.

Comment: I Have a small side question, not worth asking again. The button's text is not neatly aligned in the vertical Center. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks centered to me in the fiddle.  The dark grey bottom border is thicker than the light grey top border so maybe it is just an illusion.